# Google App Engine JPA multi level parent child relationship

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, google-cloud-datastore

I am using GAE JPA. The relationship I have is as below:

DummyParent has n users and each user has n items. DummyParent --> User --> Item

When persisting DummyParent only with user and without item my code works. But having a multi level parent relationship is not working.

```
@Entity
public class DummyParent{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;
@OneToMany(targetEntity=User.class, mappedBy="dummyP", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private ArrayList<User> users;
}

@Entity
public class User {

   @Id
       @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Key key;

   @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
   private DummyParent dummyP;

   private long id;
   @OneToMany(targetEntity=Item.class, mappedBy="likedits", fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
   public Set<Item> likeditemlist = new HashSet<Item>();
    }


    @Entity
    public class Item {
         public String name;
         @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
         private User likedits;
    }
```

Code to persist:

```
DummyParent dp = new DummyParent():
for(FbUser fu : fbuserlist) {
           User user = new User();
           user.likeditemlist.addAll(items);
           user.setName(fu.getName());
               dp.users.add(user);
               // Excluded try catch here It is there in my code
 }
                em.persist(dp);
                em.close();
```

Getting the following exception while on em.close();

```
Caused by: com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils$ChildWithWrongParentException: Detected attempt to establish User(no-id-yet) as the parent of DummyParent(1)/User(101)/Item(105) but the entity identified by DummyParent(1)/User(101)/Item(105) is already a child of DummyParent(1)/User(101).  A parent cannot be established or changed once an object has been persisted.
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.extractChildKey(EntityUtils.java:941)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.getDatastoreObjectForCollection(StoreFieldManager.java:967)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.storeFieldInEntity(StoreFieldManager.java:394)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.StoreFieldManager.storeObjectField(StoreFieldManager.java:185)
at org.datanucleus.state.AbstractStateManager.providedObjectField(AbstractStateManager.java:1447)
```

Comment: Can you include the code where you create items?  The first line in your error describes your problem, at least one of the items has already been created with another User as parent.

Comment: Thank you actually, the problem was with the data not the way I was using JPA.